# Android get image path from captured image

Tags: java, android, uri, android-camera-intent

I was having some problem when trying to get the image path from captured image. When my camera button on click:

```
takePickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

And then the codes where I try to load the captured image to image view and get the string to pass it to Async Http Post:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {               
            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            final String[] p1 = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
                    };
            Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");
            if ( c1.moveToFirst() ) {
            String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/" +c1.getInt(0);
             Uri uri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
                try {
                  Bitmap bm = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
                } finally {

                }
                params.put("filename", uristringpic);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

However, by doing this, the captured image is already set to the image view. But then when I try to print out the uristringpic, it is empty. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try smth like this

```
Uri photoUri;

takePickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

Now after image taken you have image uri in photoUri var.

If you'll need real path just use

```
public static String getPathFromMediaUri(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to set the image captured to my image view and at the same time I need to get a string imgPath to pass it as params to my servlet

Comment: @Denise try 
imgPath = getPathFromMediaUri(photoUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Nope, with these codes, the image is not set to imgView after the photo capturing

Comment: @Denise code i provided in previous comment should be executed in onActivityResult

Comment: I posted another thread with clearer message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500870/android-capture-image-send-to-servlet Help me take a look :)

Comment: If you save the uri like this as an object variable of your activity, then you need to be careful and save the property in onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onRestoreInstanceState() or else Android could destroy the Activity object while the camera is up, and then when it re-creates your Activity, your uri object variable will be uninitialized.  Learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could insert a putExtra uri before you start the camera intent where image would be saved once the user takes a photo like this

create a class

```
public class UriHelper { 
Context mContext;

public UriHelper(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

// >> CHECK IF SD CARD IS MOUNTED 
// >> USE environment.getExternalStorageState() 

// 1) GET EXTERNAL STORAGE DIRECTORY 
// 2) CREATE THE SUBDIRECTORY 
// 3) CREATE A FILE NAME 
// 4) CREATE THE FILE AND RETURN ITS URI 
// >> use uri.fromFile()
public Uri getFileUri() {

    File mediaFile;
    if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
        // 1) Get the external storage directory

        String appName = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "app name is " + appName);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                appName);

        // 2) Create our subdirectory
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Storage doest not exists");
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                // Error
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "passed here");
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Failed to create Directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // 3) Create a file name
        // 4) Create the file

        Date now = new Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.US).format(now);
        String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator;
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Path is" + path);
        mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Created :" + Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
        return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    } else
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "STORAGE NOT AVAILABLE");
    return null;
}

private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    boolean check = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
  }
}
```

and in your activity

```
Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                        UriHelper ur = new UriHelper( this );
                        mPhotoUri = ur.getFileUri(); 
                        if (mPhotoUri != null) {
                        takePhotoIntent .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
                            startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO );
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText( this , "There was an error",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
```

then you could use the uri path directly to imageview inside activity result